# Why I am Getting different Gps coordinates in same location from NETWORK_PROVIDER?

Tags: android, gps

i am getting different Gps coordinates in same location why its happening. But i need to change gps coordinates only moves after 10 meters . How can i do that.

Here is my code.

```
  private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; 
            private  static final float MIN_GEOGRAPHIC_POOLING_DISTANCE = (float)10.0;


 double myLat_Values;
        double myLog_Vaues;


locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MIN_GEOGRAPHIC_POOLING_DISTANCE, new MyLocationListener());


private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            longitude_str = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            latitude_str = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());

             Double longitude_number = Double.valueOf(longitude_str);
                 DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.000000");
                longitude_message = dec.format(longitude_number);

             Double latitude_number = Double.valueOf(latitude_str);
             DecimalFormat decim = new DecimalFormat("#.000000");
                latitude_message = decim.format(latitude_number);

                try
                {
                    myLat_Values = Double.valueOf(latitude_message);  
                    myLog_Vaues = Double.valueOf(longitude_message);
                }
                catch(NullPointerException ex)
                {
                    myLat_Values = 0;
                    myLog_Vaues = 0;
                }

     System.out.println("GPS Values Clockout:"+myLat_Values+"-"+myLog_Vaues);

        }       

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {}
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}      
    }
```

also i used these into manifestfile :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I used this [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html)

please anybody give a suggestion how to solve my problem.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: remove ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION uses permission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use NETWORK_PROVIDER ,it returns GPS co-ordinates based on the Network Service Provider you are using. But when you are using GPS_PROVIDER it returns GPS co-ordinates based on the satelites.

For [Accuracy Criteria](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html), add following code,

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);  
locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

- [ACCURACY_HIGH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#ACCURACY_HIGH) less than 100 meters
- [ACCURACY_MEDIUM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#ACCURACY_MEDIUM) between 100 - 500 meters
- [ACCURACY_LOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#ACCURACY_LOW) greater than 500 meters

Also, you need to declare following GPS Permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: i tried using above permission still i am getting different gps coordinates in same location when i tested multiple time in same location it gives multiple gps coordinates. why it happening? i need same gps coordinates at same location, and if moves after 10 meters i need to change those gps values.

Comment: can you give me samples of the locations which you are getting ?

Comment: lat:17.453443, long:78.386233, lat :17.453654 long :78.386255

Comment: that is one value, i mean various value of same location using different providers, got it ?

Comment: that is two different values in same location, please observe the last 3 digits the above two different gps values in same location.

Comment: ok, well you will not 100% accurate result ever, however you can improve accuracy in lat-lon points.

Comment: ya.. its working some better , in latitude and longitude values upto 4 digits same values after the point, but remaining last digits are different. by the by is it change gps values after 10 meters by using my code.

Comment: You do realise that the values you posted are a few centimetres apart?  You will never get exactly the same values from 2 different providers but with a simple bounds check, you can say that these are the same - e.g. if < 50cm.